# Change appearance of UIStepper

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

UIStepper is very convenient but I want to change the appearance of it, I need to have customized icon not the plus and minus and also I want to change the color of the control. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not possible.  Please file a bug requesting this feature:  https://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot presently do this. You'll have to write a custom `UIControl` object if you want to customize the icons.

From the [UIStepper Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStepper_Class/Reference/Reference.html), the only parameters you can change are

```
  continuous  property
  autorepeat  property
  wraps  property
  minimumValue  property
  maximumValue  property
  stepValue  property

  value  property
```

You cannot customize the icons.

However, since it is a subclass of `UIView`, you can try changing the `backgroundColor`.

Comment: Changing the `backgroundColor` won't work, due to decisions in how `UIStepper` was implemented.  The questioner should file a bug:  https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: I see that sucks, anyway is there open source alternative? thanks for the answer by the way.

Answer (score 16):

As of iOS 6.0 you can use  `- (UIImage *)decrementImageForState:(UIControlState)state` and `- (UIImage *)incrementImageForState:(UIControlState)state` to change the labels on the UIStepper control.

This works for iOS 6.0:

`[_stepper setDecrementImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"decrementIcon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Comment: Works fine. This should be the accepted answer if on iOS >= 6.

Answer (score 5):

This works:

```
[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIStepper class], nil] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIStepper class], nil] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"highlighted.png"]  forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIStepper class], nil] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"disabled.png"]  forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

Not sure how future proof it is though.

Comment: Nice find. Any way to set different images for the left and right controls?

Comment: @AndreiStoleru I assume you're targeting ios5 and mean the + increment and - decrement images. Not without subclassing or adding a category on UIStepper. But you can customize the divider with [[UIImageView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIStepper class], nil] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"divider.png"]];

Comment: `appearanceWhenContainedIn` was deprecated in iOS 9 and it is not longer recommended for use, in case people from the future arrive here.

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution that works for me.

Platform iOS 7.1

```
[stepper setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[stepper setDividerImage:[UIImage new] forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

The result is only increment, decrement images are visible.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the Swift 4.0 version:

```
stepper.setDecrementImage(UIImage(named: "yourDecrementImage.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
stepper.setIncrementImage(UIImage(named: "yourIncrementImage.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
```

I also found that shrinking custom images to fit into the stepper buttons would blur them. This is the only extension function I found that properly shrunk the images down without blurring:

```
extension UIImage {
  func resize(targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:targetSize).image { _ in
            self.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always step through the UIViews and guess, too. Anyway, this is my code, which doesn't answer the question directly, but is kind of neat.

```
@implementation UIStepper (Util)

- (void) fixForIos7 {
    if (!IS_IOS7)
        return;
    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        UIButton *button = (UIButton*)view;
        [button setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: StepperControl]

This gist I wrote shows creating a **StepperControl** as a subclass and set custom style of plus/minus.

P.S I have added a label image in the middle as the divider image.

```
func image(fromView view: UIView) -> UIImage
```

In regard your question, you can remove the logic for the label and instead just set blank `UIImage()` for the divider image.

[StepperControl.swift](https://gist.github.com/mazen-kasser/e133ff3797d9e2393eb604a57941c789)