# UIStepper, change plus and minus images

Tags: ios, xcode, image, background, uistepper

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change appearance of UIStepper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762512/change-appearance-of-uistepper)

I want to customize a UIStepper, I can change the background image with a code like this:

```
[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[autoUpdateStepper class], nil] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"disabled.png"]  forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

and I can change the + and - image with this:

```
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

but of course change the picture for both symbols, how can I get a different picture for plus and minus?

thanks!

Comment: My question is different, I want to change the plus and minus images, not the backgrounds..

Comment: [stepper setIncrementImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BUTTON_PLUS.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[stepper setDecrementImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BUTTON_MINUS.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: UIImage *incrementImageFromFile = [UIImage imageNamed:@"plus.png"];
    UIImage *incrementImage = [incrementImageFromFile imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    
    // For Normal state
    [stepper setIncrementImage:incrementImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];