# UIStepper Customization Results in Blue Rectangles

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistepper

I've been trying to customizing the looks of a **UIStepper** object added over Interface Builder.  In reference to a topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762512/change-appearance-of-uistepper) and others, I've added a few lines of code to viewDidLoad.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [[UIStepper appearance] setIncrementImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stepperupImage.tif"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[UIStepper appearance] setDecrementImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stepperdownImage.tif"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

The result is the blue rectangles of death as shown below.  UIStepper doesn't have a property like UIButtonTypeCustom for UIButton.  Does anybody know how to fix this problem?  My deployment target is iOS 8.0.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Are your images fully opaque, or do they have transparency?

Comment: Yes and No.  Whether I pack PNG images or JPEG images in Tiff files doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Have you set the images to render as “Always Original”?

Comment: I don't know what that means.  Elaborate your point, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To render images that don’t have transparency as they originally were, either:

- Change the “Render As” setting to “Original Image”<sup>(.xcasset files only)</sup>:
  [image: Under the slider tab, in the Image Set box]

— or —

- Change the rendering mode in code [(docs)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/imageWithRenderingMode):

  ```
  UIImage *image;
  image = [image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
  ```

In your case,the code would look like this:

```
[[UIStepper appearance] setIncrementImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"stepperupImage.tif"] imageWithRenderingMode: UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UIStepper appearance] setDecrementImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"stepperdownImage.tif"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Yes, that does it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage *incrementImageFromFile = [UIImage imageNamed:@"plus.png"];
UIImage *incrementImage = [incrementImageFromFile imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

UIImage *decrementImageFromFile = [UIImage imageNamed:@"minus.png"];
UIImage *decrementImage = [decrementImageFromFile imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];



// For Normal state
[stepper setIncrementImage:incrementImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[stepper setDecrementImage:decrementImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// For Highlighted state
[stepper setIncrementImage:incrementImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[stepper setDecrementImage:decrementImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```